# Circular graph common inner nodes, in NP

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, np

I am having a hard time figuring out this problem.

The problem is: We have a circular undirected graph `G`. We start at some node, and then take circular paths throughout the graph to arrive back at the starting node. We want to know if there is some list of `k` nodes inside the graph that must always be taken for every path in the graph. The problem is pretty much, do these `k` nodes exist?

I need to prove that this problem is in **NP**. However, not too sure how to do this.

To prove it's in NP, I need to be able to verify the solution. However, I'm not even sure how to start with the problem itself as I haven't seen something similar to this before. Could anyone lend some advice? Does anyone know an equivalent problem to this that could help with the verification?

[image]

For example, for starting node `s`, we always need to traverse `b`. So the set `k = {b}`

Input: Undirected graph G = (V, E), integer k.
Question: Is there a set S of k vertices such that every cycle in the graph includes at least one
vertex of S?

A verifier algorithm can't simply take a set S of k nodes and enumerate every cycle in the graph to check if it contains at least one vertex in S. There may be exponentially many cycles in the graph, and the verifier algorithm needs to run in polynomial time. It needs to be smarter than this.

Comment: You need to prove it's NP to NP-Complete ?

Comment: No, just need to show that it's in NP. Aka, a verification or certificate I think.

Comment: Actually, yes. Sorry, NP to NP-Complete would imply its in NP. Sorry about that.

Comment: I am probably missing something then. Given the graph, and a set of nodes - if you remove them from the graph, and its not cyclic anymore (verifiable by a BFS) - these nodes are indeed essential to the graph.

Comment: Hmm. Well, we don't necessarily know from the start which nodes are within `k`. So, we can't remove them from the start. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: If it's an undirected graph, can't you always just do `a->b->a`?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You [cannot repeat edges or vertices for a circular path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728353/doesnt-every-undirected-graph-have-a-cycle-eg-a-b-a-for-nodes-a-and) (except the first and last vertex).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only the starting vertex (which is the ending vertex) can be repeated. We basically need to find k nodes (in your example b), that must always be travelled in the graph. They are kind of like the "central" nodes of the graph. Need to show that this is NP.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I have added a picture as an example. In this example, for every path, from s->s we need to traverse b. So, k = {b}.

Comment: @amit pls see picture.

Comment: I don’t think that it’s in NP.  Consider this approach: 1) find any cycle in the graph, call the vertices in this cycle S.  2) for each node in S, try to find a cycle in the graph with that node removed.  If you can find a cycle, then that node is not one of your K nodes, if you cannot find a cycle then it is in K.  I think that this algorithm would be approx. `O(n^2 * log(n))`.  That’s well below NP equivalence.

Comment: It seems to me that you can indeed verify it by removing the nodes and testing if the remainder is cyclic, as @amit suggested. If you are confused how we know which those *k* nodes are, well they are your certificate. So the verifying algorithm gets them as input. And a DFS can indeed be done in polynomial time.

Comment: @RBarryYoung P is contained in NP

Comment: @zvonimir What is your definition of a "circular undirected graph"? Is it any graph that contains circular paths, or a graph that contains a Hamiltonian circuit?

Comment: @Berthur thanks so much for that advice, I think that is the correct approach. Sorry I am new to the NP concepts. :)

Comment: @user3386109 sorry if it wasn't clear. Its just an undirected graph that contains circular paths.

Comment: @RBarryYoung hmm, well seeing that I have to show that its in NP, I'm not sure..

Comment: @Berthur hmm, so I re-read and it says: "Is there a set S of k vertices such that every cycle in the graph includes at least one vertex of S?" Do you think this would change anything?

Comment: @zvonimir Lol, that completely changes the problem.

Comment: @zvonimir Oh, so every cycle does not need to include ALL of them?

Comment: @zvonimir That problem definition seems odd. Then you can just spam a lot of vertices into the set and get *k* as high as you want. Your original definition makes more sense to me :)

Comment: With the new problem definition, you need to count the number of disjoint cycles. So the emphasis is on finding the smallest cycles in the graph. A simple example is a [bowtie graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph) with node 's' in the middle. The graph has 2 disjoint cycles, so `k` has to be at least 2.

Comment: @zvonimir You need to [edit] the question and post the actual problem statement.

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry! Lol, I have updated the question. :3 Please see the original statement below the graph. Note that we can't just enumerate over `k` as it could be too expensive to verify.

Comment: @user3386109 disjoint cycles sounds like it makes sense! Do you think I might be able to employ that as a verifier?

Answer (score 1):

To verify a problem is in [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) (Not [NPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness)), you need to get the input of the problem, and a polynomial size verification input - and using it, determine if the answer to the decision problem of the original input is true or false, in Polynomial time (This is equivalent definition to using Non-deterministic turing machine).

- In your case, the input to the problem is `G=(V,E)`, and some integer `k`.
- The verifying string will be a set `S` with the candidate set of nodes.

Now, given these inputs - first check `|S| = k`, and then create `G' = (V', E')`, where:

```
V' = V\S
E' = { (u,v) | (u,v) in E and u in V' and v in V' }
```

Now, do a DFS form each of the nodes in V'. DFS takes polynomial time, and you need to do it polynomial number of times - so still polynomial time complexity. You are searching if there is a cycle in V' (reaching the same node you started from).

- If you find such, the answer to the problem is true (there is such set of size `k`).
- Otherwise, it's false (there isn't such set).